# Is there a way to group data in a manner that ensures equal sum of data in each group?

Tags: dolphindb, divide

I have a text file rNum.txt containing two columns of data: “sum_count“ and “sID“. I want to divide the values in “sID”  into 5 groups so that the sum of values in the “sum_count” column in each group is equal. And I wish to generate an output table with two columns:

- The one contains the sums of “sum_count“ equal among the groups.
- The other one contains comma-separated strings, each of which
  consists of the values of “sID“ within each group.

Can anyone help me to do this? Roughly balanced grouping result is acceptable.

The text file is as follows:

```
sID,sum_count
600,248590
308,243576
68,241299
834,237894
28,226598
344,222979
204,215209
84,213406
566,205764
711,204535
191,203396
704,203018
404,197864
800,197206
376,188989
768,187860
484,187622
96,185154
860,183154
152,181839
686,172126
72,171247
608,168685
496,168110
426,166161
258,161099
414,159241
504,157796
659,155767
604,148451
891,147926
454,145888
188,143981
417,143902
818,141697
729,138812
320,137801
352,135855
422,133020
446,128642
388,126211
48,125516
24,112758
788,112308
400,111371
384,110645
50,107253
890,106425
678,105518
222,101320
740,99498
670,91872
12,90922
340,88999
364,87318
646,87255
760,87239
862,86322
748,84691
231,83025
242,82562
558,79004
591,76360
120,73615
108,70558
450,70306
894,69767
52,69191
192,66945
116,65504
694,63390
524,62721
540,61302
626,59915
598,58435
136,57519
882,57371
634,54833
716,54558
466,48417
275,46842
234,46000
530,45897
854,45797
178,45584
434,44889
736,44444
20,43103
418,42171
662,41288
266,40006
762,38497
324,35050
296,33726
562,33681
356,33324
44,33280
175,31755
60,31081
533,30973
474,30773
638,30247
312,30023
232,29830
212,29416
132,29323
548,29038
795,28680
270,28398
90,27638
776,26064
585,25706
459,25504
304,24683
887,24577
478,23209
588,21647
254,19260
64,19140
583,18960
174,18131
886,17050
4,16575
230,15971
430,15577
500,15577
590,15394
262,14209
796,13796
200,13248
148,12156
660,12109
532,11731
876,11215
868,10530
720,9829
140,9534
658,9486
461,8791
850,7830
624,6548
278,6196
706,6186
184,4490
798,4006
666,2738
332,1694
570,1137
835,165
368,140
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the data can be roughly distributed by using the DolphinDB built-in function `volumeBar`:

```
t = loadText("/home/data/rNum.txt")
select sum(sum_count) as sum, toArray(sID) from t group by volumeBar(t.sum_count, 0.2)
```

[image]